# How can i skip the nth row in azure data factory copy activity?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, csv, azure-data-factory

This is the table i want to save in the database and this is the row that causes problems:
[image]

When i try to sink the whole table,this error pops out:

[image]

But when i skip the first 4 rows the copy activity debugs normally. Also the error mentions the column delimiter,but this is my setting, which do not seem wrong to me.

[image]

What is the best solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better create a copy of the file without the nth row that you want to skip. Another option, open the file and display the column delimiter. There's a chance there's some hidden content that is breaking the delimiters.

For the first option, you can use Azure Functions to create the cleaned file.

Answer (score 0):

In the copy activity settings, you could change the fault tolerance settings. Enable Skip Incompatible row to true and you could set the log path to a file in a data lake/storage account. When this is enabled, the copy activiy doesn't fail and instead logs these skipped rows to the specified file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance#configuration-1

You would have to manually look at the log file and decide what should happen with the skipped rows.